# how to capture the click of a simple button in bonita studio?

Tags: javascript, java, groovy, bonita

good morning the reason for my question is that I want to capture the click of a simple button since I am doing a form that has 3 buttons which depending on the button that the user clicks will open the form that corresponds to the button, but I do not know how to perform the procedure tried to do an actionlistener but it did not work and I have no idea how to perform the procedure I have been looking for information on the subject but I can not find any information that I am using I am new used bonitasoft, I am using a 6.x form with the groovy editor and the Bonitasoft version is 7.3, any information on how to do this procedure would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> information on the subject is forum [SimpleButton - How to use it?](https://community.bonitasoft.com/questions-and-answers/simplebutton-how-use-it)
>
> ```js
> onclick="alert('I am an alert box!')"
> ```